# GUI appears empty?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, visible

I'm making a Library list that holds media items. I'd like to start testing the buttons but when I load the program nothing appears. Looking through I can't find any problems but there has to be one.

Here's my JFrame class:

```
public class LibraryGUI extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public LibraryGUI() {
        Library lib = new Library();
        setTitle("Library");
        setSize(500, 750);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Font f = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 20);
        JLabel listLab = new JLabel("Library List");
        listLab.setFont(f);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        JList list = new JList();
        list.setFont(f);
        list.setListData(lib.listAllItems());
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setFont(f);
        JButton plus = new JButton("Add Item");
        buttons.add(plus);
        JButton loan = new JButton("Loan Item");
        buttons.add(loan);
        JButton retur = new JButton("Return Item");
        buttons.add(retur);
        JButton delete = new JButton("Delete Item");
        buttons.add(delete);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner dog = new Scanner(System.in);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(listLab, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the title of the item?");
                String title = dog.nextLine();
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the format of the item?");
                String format = dog.nextLine();
                addNewItem(title, format);
            }
        });
        retur.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the title you are returning?");
                String title2 = dog.nextLine();
                markItemReturned(title2);
            }
        });
        loan.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Scanner bob = new Scanner(System.in);
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the title?");
                String title1 = bob.nextLine();
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
                String name = bob.nextLine();
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the date?");
                String date = bob.nextLine();
                markItemOnLoan(title1, name, date);
            }
        });
        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the title?");
                String title = dog.nextLine();
                delete(title);
            }
        }); 
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: How do you test? Do you have a `main()` method?

Comment: Are you adding the panel to the frame?

Comment: Looks to me like the panel is never added to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write `add(panel);` at the end of your code, as you want your `JPanel` to be shown in your `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

You never add your `JPanel "panel"` to your frame. Do it like this:

```
add(panel);
```

Add it just before your call to `setVisible(true);`

Comment: Thanks, but now the GUI is having trouble closing when I press the close, and pressing the plus button only bring up the first window then nothing.

Comment: To get the value of the dialog, you have to use `String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the title of the item?");` instead of `String title = dog.nextLine();`. The second way waits for you to enter text in the console.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks. I'm getting an error on my JList that says it needs the generic types to be parameterized or something like that. "The method setListData(Object[]) belongs to the raw type JList. References to generic type JList<E> should be parameterized"

Comment: What is the return type of the `lib.listAllItems` method?